# Fixing Forced Reflow when source is jQuery

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to improve the page load and the timeline is showing long frames and forced reflow warnings. When I look at the offending scripts (purple bars in the screnshot) they all point to jquery.min.js.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this further or fix the issue.

[image: Timeline view of the page load]

Comment: I have the same problem. It took me a long time to figure out that the cpu was maxing out on page reload. Apparently something in jquery is creating huge forced reflows. The codebase I'm working on is abysmally badly written, but still, jquery seems to be at the root of this particular problem.